# Sizing empty divs with percentages

Tags: jquery, html, css, percentage

So long story short I had an idea for a website which would consist of 2 big Divs on top, 1 thin horizontal Div in the middle and another 2 big Divs down low. These divs wouldn't have much text or information on them, only a H2 and a subtitle maybe.

I want this design to be height and width flexible, so I set the Divs height/width on percentages. However they are only as big as the elements inside. I have set the body to have 100% height/width.

I tried this jQuery code to re size the body according to the user's screen height/width but it didn't work.

```
$("body").css("height","$(window).height()");
$("body").css("width", "$(window).width()");
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

As asked, here's the HTML

```
    <body>
    <div id="aboutMe">
        <h2>About Me</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="portfolio">
        <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="central">
        <h2>Leonardo</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="blog">
        <h2>Blog</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="contato">
        <h2>Contact</h2>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready() {
            $("body").css("height","$(window).height()");
            $("body").css("width", "$(window).width()");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

And the CSS

```
.clear {
clear: both;
}

body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
/* ABOUT ME */
#aboutMe {
height: 45%;
width: 50%;
float: left;
background-color: #E89C0C;
}


/* FIM ABOUT ME */
#body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
/* PORTFOLIO */
#portfolio {
height: 45%;
width: 50%;
float: right;
background-image: #53FF00;
}


/* FIM PORTFOLIO */

/* CENTRAL */
#central {
height: 10%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000000;
}

/* FIM CENTRAL */

/* BLOG */
#blog {
height: 45%;
width: 50%;
float: left;
background-color: #AB0DFF;
}

/* FIM BLOG */

/* CONTATO */
#contato {
height: 45%;
width: 50%;
float: right;
background-color: #0CB6E8; 
}

/* FIM CONTATO */
```

Comment: Please share your HTML too. Also, I'm not familiar with jQuery, so I'm not sure, but have you tried `$("body").css("height",$(window).height()+"px")` or something like that?

Comment: shared the code, just tried that and it also didn't work, but thank you for the idea!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pure CSS Solution - CSS Table Wireframe

Your layout is actually more complex than it seems, so give this modern CSS solution a test and see what you think.

It will have 3 rows, and each section within that row will fill both the horizontal and vertical space. Because the DIVS that hold the content are nested, each row is customizable. At a minimum, it will expand to fill the browser window, and create a vertical scroll bar for long content. To see it work, resize the browser window, and zoom/change the font size (ctrl + or -).

To control the DIV wireframe, it uses the CSS display:table settings.
**Note: This uses CSS and DIV tags for the wireframe, and should not be confused with the old-school HTML table layouts. It uses noooo HTML table tags.**

Some of the benefits of using display:table settings are:

- Creates a robust wireframe
- The table cells will expand vertically to match the tallest content in neighboring cells
- The current design wraps around long horizontal content, so if your wireframe expands past the browser viewport, it include all the content.
- With nesting, it can create stable complex layouts.

Just like floats and inline-block, there are some negatives with CSS display:table:

- When you set position:relative on a DIV with a table display value, the relative position will be ignored. So just nest a position:relative div inside the display:table element. You can then absolutely position any children.
- It has great support except for IE6 or IE7. To support these browsers, use a table htc polyfill.
- Anonymous Table Elements (browser adds implied/missing table elements) can be unpredictable. So for a wireframe, fully formed nested divs were used for stability.
- There isn't a colspan or rowspan in the CSS table settings

Give this a through test because there's probably some stuff that was overlooked, but it'll get you in the ballpark.

- [Table Support at Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=table)
- [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/f4oc7sLt/)

---

CSS

```
html{
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
}

body { 
height:100%;
width:100%;
font-size:1em;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;  
}

div {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;  
}

h2, p {
margin:0;
padding:.5em;
}

.wrapper {
height:100%;
width:100%;
display:table;
border-style:none;
border-collapse:collapse;
background-color:#E2EFF3;
}

.nested {
height:100%;
width:100%;
display:table;
border-style:none;
border-collapse:collapse;
}

.nested-row {
display:table-row;
}

.row-top,  .row-center, .row-bottom {
display: table-row;
}

.cell-top {
display:table-cell;
height:45%;
}

.cell-center {
display:table-cell;
height:10%;
}

.cell-bottom {
display:table-cell;
height:45%;
}

#aboutMe {
display:table-cell;
width:50%;
background-color:#E4E7EF;
}

 #portfolio {
display:table-cell;
width:50%;
background-color:#DEE0EB;
}

#central {
display:table-cell;
width:100%;
background-color: #A5A9BC;
}
   
#blog {
display:table-cell;
width:70%;
background-color:#697078;
}

#contato {
display:table-cell;
width:30%;
background-color:#595E71;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<div class="row-top">
<div class="cell-top">
<div class="nested">
<div class="nested-row">
<div id="aboutMe">
<h2>About Me</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="portfolio"><h2>Portfolio</h2></div>
</div><!-- end nested row -->
</div><!-- end nested -->
</div><!-- end cell top -->
</div><!-- end row top-->


<div class="row-center">
<div class="cell-center">
<div class="nested">
<div class="nested-row">
<div id="central"><h2>Leonardo</h2></div>
</div><!-- end nested row -->
</div><!-- end nested -->
</div><!-- end cell center -->
</div><!-- end row center-->

<div class="row-bottom">
<div class="cell-bottom">
<div class="nested">
<div class="nested-row">
<div id="blog">
<h2>Blog</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="contato"><h2>Contact</h2></div>
</div><!-- end nested row -->
</div><!-- end nested -->
</div><!-- end cell bottom -->
</div><!-- end row bottom-->

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: You're welcome:) I added a media query example in the JSFiddle that stacks the DIVs underneath each other by changing the various table displays to display:block, for small screen sizes/handheld devices that are 28em or less. This makes the wireframe responsive. It's commented out because it needs more testing. And of course IE6, IE7, and IE8 don't recognize media queries, so it'll need a media query htc polyfill, if you want to support those browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You have it as a string, not the actual pass-through variable.

You can't put quotes around a variable name and expect it to be rendered to anything else.

You would have to do it like this instead to return the actual height:

```
$("body").height($(window).height());
```

---

Your code, like the code below, will only return `$(window).height()` as a string and not the actual height.  Additionally, it will break your code because the `.height()` function expects a height input, not a string of random text.

```
$("body").height("$(window).height()");
```

Also, you may want to consider re-evaluating your logic here, because the `body` will in most cases always be as big as the `window`, so this code is sort of pointless, since the browser already does this. If you're trying to always make sure the body is at 100% height, you might want to look into using css `position`, and target a `div` rather than the `body` element.